# Virus PUA.Script.PDF.EmbededJS-1

Tags: 12.04, viruses, antivirus, clamav

ClamTK reported a thread named `PUA.Script.PDF.EmbededJS-1` when I scan my documents, but did not provide more details.

Is it a Windows virus or Linux virus, what this virus does, how this spreads?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

It's a false positive, don't worry.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How can you be *sure* this is a false positive!?

Comment: [http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/clamav/win32/52184](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/clamav/win32/52184)